# Greek acute accent only works in Dash in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout

I recently erased my Lubuntu 18.04 install and installed Ubuntu 16.04.5. While I was setting up the system after the installation, I noticed something strange. That has never happened to me before, even on an older installation of 16.04.

I created a keyboard shortcut and at the description the tone was before the letter. For example, the Greek word for "Good morning" is "Καλημέρα" (kalimera). When I type in the Dash it's fine, however, when I type outside the Dash it shows up as "Καλημ´ερα" (the acute accent does not "belong" to the letter).

Can anyone help me? Because I am really baffled.

*P.S. Everyone is welcome, but because I'm Greek, if there are Greek people on here who know how to solve this I would really appreciate it. Just wanted to make it clear so that there are no misunderstandings.*

Comment: How do you type the letter with the acute accent? What Dash are you talking about (I can guess, but I ask anyway to make it clear)? Where do you type, when you type outside Dash (give an example)?

Comment: It works for me in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (live) with the Xenial kernel, which is also maintained for 5 years. I switched with `setxkbmap gr` and used `onboard` to find the keys. I will try with 16.04.5 LTS (live) and let you know how it works.

Comment: @sudodus The Dash I'm talking about is the Unity Dash. This happens everytime I type outside Dash, even if it's Messenger, system Settings, Chrome etc.

Comment: You have an installed system and I have tested in a live system (both Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS). Can you make it work in a live system (booted from the USB pendrive or DVD disk made from the iso file (like I show in my answer)?

Comment: @sudodus OK. I also tested the onboard, no issues there. Also, it strangely works in gedit except the Dash. I'll boot from my live USB, try there and contact you.

Comment: @sudodus Tried Dash, gedit and Firefox from the live USB and the acute accent works without problems. So, that means reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87532/discussion-between-sudodus-and-bajiru).

Comment: @sudodus I am already in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it on my own. Test: `καλημέρα`. Turns out that there was some cache (aka barnacles and crust) on the home folder from the 18.04 install, possibly from `fcitx`, which messed up my keyboard a bit (I used it for Japanese input). I backed up my files, formatted the `/home` partition, reinstalled 16.04.5, restored the files and, hooray, it works now!

Also, thanks to sudodus for helping me with this and my previous issue. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @sudodus I fixed it on my own. Read the post above.

Comment: Congratulations, I'm glad that you found the problem and could fix it :-)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and 16.04.5 LTS (both live). I

- started `onboard`
- switched keyboard to Greek with `setxkbmap gr`
- used the `onboard` on-screen keyboard in order to find the keys, particularly the acute accent.
- pressed the acute accent key **`´`**
- after that pressed the **`ε`** key and got **`έ`**

It works for me in the command line window and in `gedit`. See the screenshot,

[image]

Comment: Yes, it also worked during installation, I could type my name without any issues. The problem arose after the install completed. I'll try and inform you

Comment: @Bajiru, After the installation completed --- hmmm. If you install without updating any package, then you should have the same versions as in the live system, and I think it *should* work in the same way. I suspect that some program package, that is updated & upgraded might cause the problem. -- If you like version 16.04 LTS, I would suggest that you try the first point release, 16.04.1 LTS. It might work also after installation and update & upgrade.

Comment: I don't remember if I tried typing something in before doing any upgrades and installing packages... However, I had the exact same packages on my previous 18.04 install and never had any issues.

Comment: @Bajiru, Why did you switch to 16.04.5 LTS? If you don't like Lubuntu, there are several other flavours of 18.04.1 LTS to try, standard Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, ... Xubuntu.

Comment: My current machine is 32-bit so... not a lot of options. I'm getting a new one in a couple of weeks so I'll just install 18.04 or 18.10 on there. But for now, 32-bit options only...